# Is it possible to use File Appenders in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, log4j, appender, rollingfileappender

So I am trying to implement Log4j feature File Appender, however I can't seem to get appengine to create the log4j file. I have the correct permissions and the folders that I want it to be located in do exist. I can't work out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a basic App Engine restriction : you can't write to the file system.

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> - write to the filesystem. Applications must use the App Engine datastore for storing persistent data. Reading from the filesystem is allowed, and all application files uploaded with the application are available.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime